# regex not replacing all occurrences bbcode style

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, bbcode

Here is my string:

`$str="[url=/someurl]Click Here[/url] [url=/someurl]Click Here2[/url]";`

Here is my code:

```
$str=preg_replace('/\[url=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/', '<a href="\1" style="text-decoration:none;color:#336699">\2</a>', $str);
```

**My output transforms the first url bbcode style portion but the second one does not get transformed as well.**

What Im looking for is a global regex replacement. **Not very good with regex so I don't really know what to do** The purpose is for the `preg_replace` to account for `both bbcode urls`

UPDATE

HERE IS my code: `$str=preg_replace('/[url=(.+?)](.+?)[\/url]/s', '<a href="\1" style="text-decoration:none;color:#336699">\2</a>', $str);`

And here is string:

```
$str="ou can call my cell phone, email or text message me via my contact info on my profile. 

[url=/profile/number]Click Here[/url]

Hope to hear from you all soon !!

[url=dasasdasd]asdasdasd[/url]";
```

HEre is my function:

```
 function bbcode($str) {
  $str=preg_replace('/\[url=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/s', '<a href="\1" style="text-decoration:none;color:#336699">\2</a>', $str);
  return $str;
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with your current example.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte theres some new lines and verbiage in between does that change the result?

Comment: Yes because the dot `.` doesn't match newlines by default. To change this behavior add the `s` modifier.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte how do i add the s modifier?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte can you please create a answer?

Comment: The modifier(s) go after the closing delimiter. http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: No, I won't because this question was asked many many many times.

Comment: $str=preg_replace('/\[url=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/s', '<a href="\1" style="text-decoration:none;color:#336699">\2</a>', $str); is what i have now and its not working

Comment: @chris85 im not seeing any difference

Comment: @chris85 i see no difference

Comment: Your most recent update, previous update, comment, and first code example are all conflicting. Please state **exactly** what you have.

Comment: @slicks1 please use modern solutions for BBCode, I recommend my own library https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode . Happy to answer any questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[]` are special characters in regex. They are character classes and allow one of the characters inside it.

See: https://regex101.com/r/mN4tN9/1

```
[url=(.+?)]
```

vs:

```
\[url=(.+?)\]
```

(regex101 seems to have stopped working so can't post second link)

for a functional demo of the replacement see: https://eval.in/610316.

Comment: i added my function

Comment: @slicks1 So the `HERE IS my code:` is not your actual code, correct?

Comment: thats part of the function its actually the same code sory

Comment: so should i not escape?

Comment: You should escape, were you escaping previously? The code works when escaped as demonstrated on regex101, previous link, and https://eval.in/610317. The `s` modifier also isn't actually needed here because the string that `.` is matching doesn't extend to the next line.